# locks on java synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

I am trying to write a java program with threads using synchronized methods. But iam not able to understand how can i display that already a thread is running when another thread invokes synchronized method in java. Can any one explain with simple example

Comment: Only one thread can be executing a synchronized method at a given time. What do you mean by "already a thread is running?"

Answer (score 3):

Here is a contrived example which shows the interleaving and blocking process. On my machine it prints:

> Thread[Thread-0,5,main] is going to call the synchronized method
>   Thread[Thread-1,5,main] is going to call the synchronized method
>   Thread[Thread-0,5,main] is in the synchronized method
>   Thread[Thread-0,5,main] is exiting the method
>   Thread[Thread-1,5,main] is in the synchronized method
>   Thread[Thread-1,5,main] is exiting the method

You can see that only one thread enters the synchronized block while the other waits.

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Test1 test = new Test1();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " is going to call the synchronized method");
                test.method();
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
        new Thread(r).start();
    }

    public synchronized void method() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " is in the synchronized method");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " is exiting the method");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to print a message when a thread tries to invoke a synchronized method while another thread is already executing it. You cannot do this with synchronized methods or blocks but you can do it using [java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface instead. The method you need is tryLock(). You can do something like this:

```
public class Test1 {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    // ...

    public void method() {
        if (lock.tryLock()) {
            try {
                // you successfully acquired the lock, do you logic here
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }                
        } else {
            // lock is hold by another thread
            System.out.println("cannot acquire a lock");
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily evolve this example to print which thread exactly holds the lock if you wish.